# Getting error while installing pod (/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:254:in `bin_path': can't find gem cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

While installing pods in my project. I am getting this error:

> /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:254:in `bin_path': can't find gem cocoapods (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
>       from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in`'

Note:- I have updated my pods to 1.1.1.
       Using macOS Sierra

Comment: So what's the question?  You updated Pods yesterday.  You install Pods today?  People usually install a program first and then update it.

Comment: I am trying to install pod in project with command "pod install" in my project directory. There i am getting this error

Answer (score 1):

Just faced the same issue. This helped me:

```
1: sudo gem uninstall cocoapods 

2: gem install cocoapods

3: pod install
```